# ArcToolbox 9.3 converted to ArcGIS 10 not working in ArcMap 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arctoolbox

I added a custom toolbox created for 9.3.1 to a ArcGIS Desktop 10 ArcMap.  Now it seemed to have disappeared.  I can't add it to ArcMap 9.3.1.

Is there a way to convert it back if that is even the issue?  Or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click on the toolbox in ArcToolbox and select *Save As* specifying 9.3 as the outgoing version.  I ran into this problem previously, it is wise to copy your 9.2, 9.3 etc toolboxes to a new location prior to loading into version 10.

I should add, that user toolboxes won't be available by default in version 10 even though they may have been so in 9.x.  You will need to re-add them to make them available.